# theyworkforyou API coming back empty in Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am really getting confused.  If I post into a browser the following link, it works, no problem, but when I ask jQuery do to it, it comes back blank, but no error.

**Link**:

http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/getConstituency?key=FU8MWTEQnvVsHC6GM7B82zie&postcode=BS345NT

**Code**:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/getConstituency?key=FU8MWTEQnvVsHC6GM7B82zie&postcode='+postcode+'&output=js',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
   }
});
```

I can change the Key, so don't worry about the fact I posted it.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: When I run it I get the error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/getConstituency?key=FU8MWTEQnvVsHC6GM7B82zie&postcode=RG2+9LA&output=js. Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: I can't find any api documentation for theworkforyou, but presumably they do no intend for you to give your API key to each of your visitors and ask their browsers to interact with the API directly.

Comment: @Quentin its right here [theyworkforyou](http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/)

Comment: @ScottSelby - looks like it sends the correct content type header for JSON so you don't need to override it in client side code.

Comment: You can't post cross-domain without CORS, and i'm pretty sure they won't allow CORS. API's with API Keys are usually intended to be used by servers, not clients.

Comment: I have tried it with both Crossdomain: true and datatype: 'json' but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is running in the context of a web page downloaded from an origin server into a browser. It tries to request a page from a different server, but this is a violation of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Javascript cannot make requests to servers other than the origin server.

The [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) technique can be used to get around this, but only if the non-origin server supports it. In this technique the javascript code dynamically creates a script tag whose src element 1) points to the non-origin server, and 2) passes (as  a query parameter) the name of a function which exists in the local javascript. The non-origin server returns the source code of a script which merely invokes the function on data provided by the non-origin server. In this way the javascript can request data from a non-origin server.

If the non-origin server does not support JSONP, then you won't be able to do what you want.